# Scala self annotated types

Tags: scala

Reading through this wonderfully written article

http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/12/19/cake-pattern-in-depth

on self type annotation, I'm wondering what would be the difference when I use self or some arbitrary name instead of this in the

```
this: UserRepositoryComponent =>
```

or

```
self: UserRepositoryComponent =>
```

or

```
user: UserRepositoryComponent =>
```

against:

```
trait DefaultUserServiceComponent extends UserServiceComponent {
      this: UserRepositoryComponent =>

      def userService = new DefaultUserService

      class DefaultUserService extends UserService {
        def findAll = userLocator.findAll

        def save(user: User) {
          userUpdater.save(user: User)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier to read.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?